# a problem about fingerdetection

Tags: ros, kinect, mit-ros-pkg

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, all. Could you help me to solve a problem? I met a problem when i was running  mit-ros-pkg fingerdetection. I could not see the hands and me in rviz. The log are as follow.

```
... logging to /home/nutan/.ros/log/9b842098-761a-11e0-a5df-00e081b5d370/roslaunch-nutan-desktop-18197.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt

started roslaunch server http://nutan-desktop:53662/

SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /rosdistro
 * /openni_node1/use_indices
 * /openni_node1/depth_registration
 * /openni_node1/image_time_offset
 * /openni_node1/depth_frame_id
 * /openni_node1/depth_mode
 * /openni_node1/debayering
 * /rosversion
 * /openni_node1/projector_depth_baseline
 * /openni_node1/rgb_frame_id
 * /openni_node1/depth_rgb_translation
 * /openni_node1/depth_time_offset
 * /openni_node1/image_mode
 * /openni_node1/shift_offset
 * /openni_node1/device_id
 * /openni_node1/depth_rgb_rotation

NODES
  /
    openni_node1 (openni_camera/openni_node)
    kinect_base_link (tf/static_transform_publisher)
    kinect_base_link1 (tf/static_transform_publisher)
    kinect_base_link2 (tf/static_transform_publisher)
    kinect_base_link3 (tf/static_transform_publisher)
    handdetector (hand_interaction/detectskelhands)
    ressetter (dynamic_reconfigure/dynparam)
    skel_tracker (skeletal_tracker/tracker)
    finger_detector (hand_interaction/analyzehands)

auto-starting new master
process[master]: started with pid [18212]
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

setting /run_id to 9b842098-761a-11e0-a5df-00e081b5d370
process[rosout-1]: started with pid [18225]
started core service [/rosout]
process[openni_node1-2]: started with pid [18233]
process[kinect_base_link-3]: started with pid [18238]
process[kinect_base_link1-4]: started with pid [18239]
process[kinect_base_link2-5]: started with pid [18240]
process[kinect_base_link3-6]: started with pid [18241]
process[handdetector-7]: started with pid [18250]
process[ressetter-8]: started with pid [18262]
process[skel_tracker-9]: started with pid [18287]
process[finger_detector-10]: started with pid [18289]
Waiting for service /openni_camera/set_parameters...
[ INFO] [1304491749.573710534]: [/openni_node1] Number devices connected: 1
[ INFO] [1304491749.574036063]: [/openni_node1] 1. device on bus 001:07 is a Xbox NUI Camera (2ae) from Microsoft (45e) with serial id 'A00364900886049A'
[ INFO] [1304491749.576213944]: [/openni_node1] searching for device with index = 1
[ INFO] [1304491749.622726452]: [/openni_node1] Opened 'Xbox NUI Camera' on bus 1:7 with serial number 'A00364900886049A'
[ INFO] [1304491749.637590700]: rgb_frame_id = '/openni_rgb_optical_frame' 
[ INFO] [1304491749.639302640]: depth_frame_id = '/openni_depth_optical_frame' 
InitFromXml failed: File not found!
[skel_tracker-9] process has died [pid 18287, exit code 4].
log files: /home/nutan/.ros/log/9b842098-761a-11e0-a5df-00e081b5d370/skel_tracker-9*.log
respawning...
[skel_tracker-9] restarting process
process[skel_tracker-9]: started with pid [18501]
InitFromXml failed: File not found!
[skel_tracker-9] process has died [pid 18501, exit code 4].
log files: /home/nutan/.ros/log/9b842098-761a-11e0-a5df-00e081b5d370/skel_tracker-9*.log
respawning...
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9886/a-problem-about-fingerdetection/) by [Nutan](https://answers.ros.org/users/170/nutan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 96 on 2011-05-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

the skel_tracker node dies in the above log, that's why you can't see your fingers in rviz. you need to get the launch file working first

---

Originally posted by [mmwise](https://answers.ros.org/users/2/mmwise/) with karma: 8372 on 2011-06-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0